# how to bind aggregated alias column with gridview

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I have following query which returning a table of aggregated column . but when i try to bind this using datatable i does not get. required result.

Table:

```
5   6   0   1   Male    2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 0   0   0
6   6   2   0   Female  2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 1   0   0
7   6   3   0   Male    2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 0   1   0
8   6   4   0   Male    2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 0   0   1
9   6   5   0   Female  2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 0   0   1
10  6   7   1   Female  2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 0   0   0
11  6   8   1   Male    2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 0   0   0
12  6   9   0   Female  2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 1   0   0
13  6   10  0   Male    2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 0   1   0
14  6   10  1   Male    2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 0   0   0
15  6   10  1   Female  2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 0   0   0
16  6   10  0   Male    2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 1   0   0
17  6   10  0   Female  2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 1   0   0
18  7   5   0   Female  2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 1   0   0
19  7   1   0   Male    2013-06-07 00:00:00.0000000 1   0   0
20  6   6   0   Female  2013-06-11 00:00:00.0000000 0   0   1
```

Query:

```
select e.Nme
      ,sum(case when m.gender='Male' then 1 else 0 end) as Male
      ,sum(case when m.gender='FeMale' then 1 else 0 end)as FeMale
      ,sum(m.seg1to5)Seg0to5
      ,sum(m.seg5to15)Seg5to15
      ,sum(m.seg15to46)Seg15to45
      ,sum(m.seg45plus)seg45plus from eventundersurv e 
  full outer join mchcmain m  
      on e.ID=m.eventid where  m.unitid=2 or e.Nme is not null group by e.Nme
```

Result:

```
Acute Diarrhea  1   0   0   1   0   0
AWD/ Suspected Cholera  0   1   0   1   0   0
Blood Grouping Tests    0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Blood Sugar Tests   0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Bloody Diarrhea     1   0   0   0   1   0
Bronchial Asthma    0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Diabetes    0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
E.P.I VACCINE   0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Follow up   0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
FP  0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Hb Tests    0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Hepatitis B Screening   0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Hepatitis C Screening   0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Hypertension    0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Injuries    0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Lower Resp. Tract Infection 0   1   0   0   0   1
Moderate Malnutrition (WfA -2 to -3Z) Orange zone   0   0   NULL    NULL NULL   NULL
Neonatal Tetanus    1   0   1   0   0   0
No. of Antenatal Consultations without Ultrasound   0   0   NULL    NULL NULL   NULL
No. of normal deliveries    0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
No. of Postnatal Consultations  0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
No. of Pregnant women referred  0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
No. of Ultrasounds performed Antenatal + Ultrasound    General Ultrasound   0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Others  0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Pregnancy Tests     0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Referred    0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Scabies     0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Skin Disease    0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Suspected Hemorrhagic Fever 0   1   0   1   0   0
Suspected Malaria   1   0   0   0   0   1
Suspected Measles   0   1   1   0   0   0
TT Vaccination of Pregnant Women    0   0   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
Unexplained Fever >38.5 3   2   2   2   1   0
Upper Resp.Tract Infection  0   2   0   1   0   1
```

I need to display results in above form on gridview. but I'm not getting result alias columns

Comment: Which columns are you trying to display in the gridview?

Comment: All columns.  Actually i need to bind these all columns to grid. which are returns by query.

Comment: Can you show the code of your Grid? That could help finding the issue